# Sort an array of seasons, starting with the current season

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have an array of 4 seasons: `Summer, Autumn, Winter, Spring`. I want to be able to keep this intrinsic order, but make the current season the first item in the array.

So, if the current season is `Winter`, the result would be: `Winter, Spring, Summer, Autumn`.

In my mind, this basically involves treating the array like a 'loop', so that if you move an element off the start, it appears at the end and vice-versa. I've got some ugly implementations of this, but I'm hoping for something nice and clean.

I'm writing in Ruby, but any language (or pseudo-code) that shows the algorithm would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, I found that Ruby's Array has the [rotate](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-rotate) method, which does exactly what is needed:

```
base_order = ['Summer', 'Autumn', 'Winter', 'Spring']

sorted_order = base_order.rotate(base_order.index('Winter'))

# Yields ['Winter', 'Spring', 'Summer', 'Autumn']
```

There's a banged version `#rotate!` which mutates the base array, too.

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution is keep elements in a **[circular linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circular_Linked_list)**, and whenever a season is changed, advance the pointer where you store the head of the list.

This will be fairly elegant and simple to use, and if you are dealing with only 4 elements - performance of linked list is really not an issue here.

Comment: You're right, it is a circular linked list we're talking about. My only problem is that Ruby doesn't have a CLL (or any LL) structure natively - boo. I've since found a native ruby solution - see my own answer: it's very likely using a CLL under the hood. Thanks for your help anyway - it did clear up my thinking.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mod 4` to access the array. You array looks like `[Summer, Autumn, Winter, Spring]`; create a function `get(int index, int current)` that gets the element at index `index` given that the current season is `current`, where Summer maps to 0, Autumn to 1, etc.

```
string get(int index, int current)
{  return array[ (current + index + 4) % 4 ];
}
```

This is faster and simpler than the circular-list solution. If the current season is Winter (2), then `get(1, 2)` will return 3, `get(3, 2)` will return 1.

Comment: I can't quite see how this would fit into an algorithm to sort the array. What do I do with the result of `get`?

Comment: You use it to access the array: array[ get(1, 2) ] is Spring. Notice that you can use negative values too for the index. You don't have to do any sorting..it's direct access.

Comment: Sorry - but it's the sorting I'm after, not so much direct access. I always need all four items in the array, starting from a particular one, but retaining the intrinsic the array has in the beginning. Check @amit's answer, or Ruby's #rotate method on Array. Thanks anyway.